# IntelliSense: Cannot open source file in include path

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am authoring a C++ project with Visual Studio 2013 Professional and I encountered a problem I have never encountered before.

In one of my source files I am including a third-party header file like this:

```
#include 'sqlcli1.h'
```

This file (and other files of the same set) are located in a an external directory (not in the VS solution), so **I have** added it to the search path using *Additional include paths* under project's *Properties*.

The solution **does build** succesfuuly, so I am sure my external header file is referenced correctly. IntelliSense, however, still **doesn't see** it and complains about not being able to open source file `'sqlcli1.h'`. It does not prevent me from building the project, but it makes editing it much harder.

Why does this happen and what should I do?

Comment: why use `'`? Did you try to replace them with `"` or `<` and `>`? Maybe then IntelliSense will hook up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to delete files related to Intellisense in your solution directory? Go to `.vs\(your solution name)\v(VS version)\`, delete `Browse.VC.db` and `ipch` directory. VS will rebuild the IntelliSense database and it may help solve your problem.

Comment: What is the "IntelliSense file"? I did a web search for "IntelliSense file" but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Answer is edited. Check it out.

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't expecting a reply after this time.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I did everything above but, to no avail.  For me the problem is the *.vcxproj file.  I took the contents of a working *.vcxproj file and replaced it with the one that didn't work (changing the project name in the *.vcxproj file, of course!!)  And, Wowie Zowie!!  It works! There is probably a much more elegant solution, but this worked for me.  Also, my problem was related to a C1083 error, too.